# Tufte-Latex libertine text and math font incompatibility issue

Tags: tufte, libertine, math-fonts

I'd like to write a substantial math document with the `tufte-book` class, with a few minor changes.  My first issue is that, after loading my preferred font of `libertine`, along with `newtxmath` to get its associated math fonts, I still get text in libertine and math in what looks like the default Palatino.  I'm compiling with `pdflatex`.  Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[nofont]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\everymath{\displaystyle}


\begin{document}


We have 
\[
\frac{d}{dx}(\sin \theta)=\cos \theta,
\]
with libertine text but math in Palatino.  Another example is the summation formula
\[
\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
\]


\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but are you sure you want `\everymath{\displaystyle}` (it makes inline math more or less unusable)

Comment: load newtxmath after libertine (since you want its math settings to win)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [Khaled Hosny's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729/khaled-hosny) fork of Linux Libertine called [Libertinus](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus) which notably includes an OpenType math font based on Linux Libertine. Switch to XeLaTeX, then add the following to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
```

With `xelatex`, the font encoding defaults to Unicocde (UTF-8), so you can drop the `fontenc` package as well as the `libertine` and `newtxmath` packages.

Here's the complete test document:

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}

We have
\[
\frac{d}{dx}(\sin \theta)=\cos \theta,
\]
with Libertinus Serif text and math in Libertinus Math.  Another example is the summation formula
\[
\sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
\]
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: Output of test document]